# submit form1 without submitting submitting form2 in flask

Tags: flask, sqlite, multiple-forms

if i am submitting form 1 then form 2 is automatically submitted and blank values of form 2 are stored in database

```
@app.route('/profile', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
@login_required
def profile():
form1 = ProfileForm1()
form2 = ProfileForm2()
if form1.validate_on_submit() and request.method=='POST':
    profile = Profile.query.filter_by(id=current_user.id).first()
    profile.name=form1.name.data
    profile.contact = form1.contact.data
    flash('Profile UPDATED (refresh to see update)')

if form2.validate_on_submit() and request.method =='POST':
    profile = Profile.query.filter_by(id=current_user.id).first()
    profile.position = form2.position.data
    profile.address = form2.address.data
    flash("Updated - refresh to see")

items = Profile.query.filter_by(id=current_user.id).first()
return render_template("profile.html", form1=form1,form2=form2,item=items)
```

both ProfileForm1 and ProfileForm2 have same database.

Note: Profile table was created in other part of code.

Edit : I changed the Validators of both forms to InputRequired() and it worked form me.

Comment: If you want to handle two forms on a page the easiest thing would be to create separate post routes on the sever for them.

Comment: thanx :) it worked for me.